# Hibernate: two sequences within a single entity with JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, sequence, hibernate-annotations

I have a mapping class using JPA annotations, and I want it to use two separate sequences for two fields:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="my_table", schema="schema") 
@SequenceGenerator(name="sequence",sequenceName="schema.local_key_sequence")
@SequenceGenerator(name="orderSequence",sequenceName="schema.message_received_sequence")
public class MyClass
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="unique_key",unique=true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="sequence")
    private long id; 

    @Column(name="sequence_received")        
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="orderSequence" )
    private long sequenceReceived;
    [...]
}
```

However, JPA forbids me from having to `@SequenceGenerator` in the Entity.  How should I do this.

Note: for clarification, I want the ID to be generated automatically from the next value of `local_key_sequence`, and sequenceReceived to be generated autonatically from `message_received_sequence`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Generated by database value on Primary keys only.

However Hibernate (Hibernate Annotations project) can support this if only field **sequenceReceived** will be also Id (part of composite Id).